# Python Error: main thread is not in main loop

Tags: python, runtime-error

Im trying to create a code that will ask for a MAC-adress and then check that at macvendors.com
At the moment Im just getting

> Error: main thread is not in main loop

The code:

```
#$language = "Python3"
#$interface = "1.0"

import sys
import requests
from requests import get
import turtle

class Macpyoui:
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api

def safe_input(input_message):
    if not sys.stdin:
        sc = turtle.Screen(); #access turtle screen
        sc.setup(0, 0); # change the screen size to zero
        return turtle.textinput("Your App Title", input_message); #prompt the user with an input dialog
    return input(str);


site = "https://api.macvendors.com/"
data = Macpyoui(site)
macaddress = safe_input("Please enter the MAC address: ")

def searchmac():
    macsend = data.api + macaddress
    vendorsearch = get(macsend).text
    if "Not Found" in vendorsearch:
        print("MAC address not found.")
    else:
        print(vendorsearch)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    searchmac()
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the error.

Comment: You probably need to use `turtle.getscreen()` instead of `turtle.Screen()`.

Comment: You are missing `turtle.done()`.

Comment: This is the full error message:
RuntimeError
Error: main Thread is not in main loop
File C:\Users\x\x\Desktop\MAClookup.py
Line: 16

sc.setup(0, 0); # change the screen size to zero